# Can I create multiple instance of same ec2 image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have requirement of creating multiple instances of the same EC2 image from lambda as the EC2 image has some Windows Processing creating PDF files. Can I launch multiple instances of the same EC2 image and pass some parameters to each ec2 instance ( say name of the bucket in S3, and names are different).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An AWS EC2 image provides essentially a snapshot of how the server should look.

This would include:

- Any packages you need installed
- Any configuration you need

If you want custom configuration applied on top you would need to either:

- Make use of [UserData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html) when you launch the instance to run those additional actions
- Create a custom AMI with the custom configuration included